# functions not working after published on playstore

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-volley

In my chat app, OTP is not coming, also exception is showing. it is still working fine on Android studio. I'm using firebase OTP service.

```
E/Volley: [42175] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPhoneNumber?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyDrX17T8Q6wHJMzBNp6lpQgsezGLnEHio8
```

It is going in this part in my PhoneAuthActivity:

```
 @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

                ErrorView.setText("There was some error in verification");
                ErrorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and one more error

```
07-21 18:14:31.581 30405-3770/? E/MyGcmListenerService: {"id":142420,"image_type":0,"image_url":"http://p16.muscdn.com/img/tos-maliva-p-0068/c9ec231abd7b46cf8ca36227615e2fad~c5_100x100.jpeg","open_url":"sslocal://aweme/detail/6572808861554576646?label=admin\u0026gd_label=click_push_recommend\u0026gid=6572808861554576646\u0026push_id=142420","text":"Beautiful wedding ","title":"","use_led":1}
07-21 18:14:31.581 30405-30405/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
07-21 18:14:31.591 30405-30405/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
07-21 18:14:
```

This is my app See: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat

NOTE: Play console - Release management - app signing - App signing certificate & Upload certificate
(shwoing 3 key including md5,sha, sh1)

Comment: Can anybody solve it, I'm ready to do whatever you want. I can send you code

Comment: When you try your app (`debug compile`) it work? Because what I think is your key api for the `release compile` is not configured for the Drive api.

Comment: @crammeur when I run from Android Studio to my samsung device, it work, I got OTP also, and able to login also. But if I download the app from playstore and do the same step, it shows exception when I click on send verification button.

Comment: @crammeur NOTE: Play console - Release management - app signing - App signing certificate & Upload certificate (shwoing 3 key including md5,sha, sh1)